# CSS3 zoom and move animation effect on img

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I'm trying to make CSS3 animation like in the slider present in [this site](http://krypton.detheme.com/).

I have tried to use the below CSS:

```
.animate-in{
  left: -20%;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
  -o-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
  -webkit-transition-property: left, -webkit-transform, opacity;
  -moz-transition-property: left, transform, opacity;
  -ms-transition-property: left, transform, opacity;
  -o-transition-property: left, transform, opacity;
  transition-property: left, transform, opacity;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 10s, 15s, 2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 10s, 15s, 2s;
  -ms-transition-duration: 10s, 15s, 2s;
  -o-transition-duration: 10s, 15s, 2s;
  transition-duration: 10s, 15s, 2s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: linear;
  -ms-transition-timing-function: linear;
  -o-transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 1s;
  -ms-transition-delay: 1s;
  -o-transition-delay: 1s;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}
```

But this CSS only made the zoom effect and I need the effect that made pic fade from right and left like the example above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve the required zoom + fade and move from left animation would be to make sure that the container is larger than the required size by n pixels and then add `translateX(npx)` also as part of the `transform` stack.

**Note:**

- I have used animations instead of transitions because animations are auto-triggered whereas transition is triggered only upon state change.
- Another way would be to animate the `background-size` and `background-position` but generally the animations that use `transform` are considered to be less problematic in terms of performance.

```css
.anim {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% + 100px);
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1000/500?random=1);
  animation: zoom-move 15s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes zoom-move {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1) translateX(-100px);
    opacity: 0.25;
  }
  13.33% {
    opacity: 1;
    /* make opacity change complete in 2s */
  }
  66.66% {
    transform: scale(1.13) translateX(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2) translateX(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
body {
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='anim'></div>
```

---

Or, another way you could achieve it is by using `transform-origin` along with `transform` (without adding any `translate`).

```css
.anim {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% + 100px);
  left: -100px;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1000/500?random=1);
  animation: zoom-move 15s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes zoom-move {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    transform-origin: -100px 50%;
    opacity: 0.25;
  }
  13.33% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    transform-origin: -100px 50%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
body {
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='anim'></div>
```